# RAILS 3.1 - unknown attribute: id on build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

When I want to use build for a many-to-many through association, I get the following error in my controller:

**unknown attribute: fte_report_option_id**

In my controller:

> def edit_clients_reports
>      @fte_report_option = FteReportOption.find(params[:id])
>      **@fte_report_option.fte_report_client_options.build**
>      end

In my first model, I have:

> class FteReportOption < ActiveRecord::Base
>
> has_many :fte_report_client_options, :dependent => :destroy
>      has_many :clients, :through => :fte_report_client_options
>      end

In my second model:

> class FteReportClientOption < ActiveRecord::Base
>      self.primary_key = "client_report_id"
>
> belongs_to :fte_report_option, :foreign_key => :option_id, :class_name => "FteReportOption"
>      belongs_to :client, :foreign_key => :client_id, :class_name => "Client"
>      end

And my third model:

> class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
>      set_primary_key "client_id"
>
> has_many :fte_report_client_options, :dependent => :destroy
>      has_many :fte_report_options, :through => :fte_report_client_options

In my migration for the join table, I have:

> create_table :fte_report_client_options, :primary_key => "client_report_id", :force => true do |t|
>        t.integer :option_id
>        t.integer :client_id
>        t.timestamps
>      end

Is anyone know what's happen?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Perhaps we should begin by reviewing the code that you've posted. 
In the `FteReportClientOption` we have `self.primary_key = "client_report_id"` which doesn't make any sense. Did you mean `set_primary_key`? 
Then, in the migration you set the primary key to a column that doesn't exist in the table. 
Problems like these can affect how Rails tries to "guess" the names of your attributes.
In all - I would strongly urge you to use Rails-standard primary keys if you do not have a really strong reason not to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your migration, change line:

```
t.integer :option_id
```

to:

```
t.integer :fte_report_option_id
```

Comment: @Adam Eberlin. Thanks very munch Adam.  I am now to debug my view called by my controller.  But my original problem is resolve.